# Calculating min/max values of a columnstore table with sys.column_store_segments

Tags: sql-server, columnstore, system-tables

I need to fetch the max and min values of an arbitrary column on a table. The table has a clustered columnstore-index, billions of rows, and hundreds of columns.

I'd like to leverage that fact that every columnstore segment already has its min and max value recorded in the sys.column_store_segments table's min_data_id and max_data_id columns. It shouldn't be necessary to access the actual table, as the columnstore segment metadata has sufficient information. But it appears that the min_data_id and max_data_id columns cannot be trusted to contain the max and min values because they may also contain references into a dictionary instead. Is there any way that I can determine whether min_data_id and max_data_id are real values vs dictionary references? If they are references, is it possible for me to access the underlying dictionary?

References:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/technet-wiki/5651.understanding-segment-elimination

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-column-store-segments-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Is it really that major to just do `SELECT MIN(value), MAX(value) FROM T`

Comment: I haven't validated this for myself but the article here claims that it would use the metadata anyway for such a query https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/t-sql-programming-sql-server/hands-on-with-columnstore-indexes-part-4-query-patterns/#:~:text=Few%20Columns%2C%20Larger%20Date%20Range